# App keep crashing while using Twillio OTP service

Tags: node.js, json, twilio

I am using Twilio for the OTP service in node.js I have made two functions in my auth-controller file

1. SendOTP
2. VerifyOTP

In SendOTp the function sends OTP to the given number it sends the OTP but after sending the OTP my App got crashed by showing this error

**ERROR 1**
node:internal/errors:464
ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

After sending the OTP I Verified my OTP using jwt tokens but when I try to verify my OTP I got another error.

**ERROR 2**
Unexpected token o in JSON at position 37
at JSON.parse ()

This is my auth-controller file

```
const otpservice = require('../services/otp-service');
const hashService = require('../services/hash-service');
const otpService = require('../services/otp-service');
const userService = require('../services/user-service');
const tokenService = require('../services/token-service');
class AuthController {

    async sendOtp(req,res){
        const {phone} = req.body;  // Our Phone Number

        if(!phone){  // IF a user dont enter a phone Number
            res.status(400).json({message:'Phone number field is required'});
        }

        const otp = await otpservice.generateOtp();   // calling function for generated otp

        const ttl = 1000 * 60 * 2; //ttl time to login 2 minutes
        const expires = Date.now() + ttl;   // Time left for otp to expire
        const data = `${phone}.${otp}.${expires}`;   // our data to be hashed
        const hash = hashService.hashOtp(data);  // hashing the data


        try{

            await otpservice.sendBySms(phone, otp);  // sending Sms
            res.json({
                hash:`${hash}.${expires}`,
                phone
            })

        }catch(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({message:"Message Sending Failed"});
            return;
        }


        res.json({hash: hash});
    }

   async verifyOtp(req, res){                // Verifying OTP
        const {otp, hash, phone} = req.body;     
        if(!otp || !hash || !phone){
            res.status(400).json({message: 'All Fields are required!'});
        }
        const [hashedOtp, expires] = hash.split('.');   // previous hash

        if(Date.now() > + expires){      // checking if OTP is not expired
            res.status(400).json({message: 'OTP is expired'});
        }

        const data = `${phone}.${otp}.${expires}`;

        const isValid = otpService.verifyOtp(hashedOtp,data);

        if(!isValid){
            res.status(400).json({message: "Invalid OTP"});
        }

        let user;
        
       


        try{
            user = await userService.findUser({phone: phone});
            if(!user){
                user = await userService.createUser({phone:phone});
            }   
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err);  
        }

        const {accessToken, refreshToken} = tokenService.generateTokens({
            _id: user._id,
            activated: false
        });

        res.cookie('refreshtoken',refreshToken,{
            maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
            httpOnly: true

        })



        res.json({accessToken});

        

    }
}

module.exports= new AuthController();
```

Kindly please tell me what is mistake I am making. I have tried my best to solve this error but couldn't find the answer. I will be very grateful to you Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

In your `sendOTP` method you are sending two responses. At the bottom of the function it looks like this:

```js
    try {
        await otpservice.sendBySms(phone, otp);  // sending Sms
        res.json({
            hash:`${hash}.${expires}`,
            phone
        })
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({message:"Message Sending Failed"});
        return;
    }

    res.json({hash: hash});
}
```

You return a response with `res.json` inside the `try`, but then after the `try/catch` block you `res.json` again. I believe that is causing the `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` error (as `res.json` will call `res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')` thus sending a header after a response has already been sent).

To fix this, you can remove that final `res.json` as there are responses made in the `try` and the `catch` block above, so it is unnecessary.

---

In your `verifyOTP` function, I'm not sure what is going on. There doesn't seem to be any JSON parsing in the body of that code. Is there something within your call to `otpService.verifyOtp(hashedOtp,data);` that is calling an API and handling return data?